# How to read the boto3 file object in opencv python3

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, boto3

I am trying to read the `AWS S3` `presigned uri` file with open-CV. But the read parameter is of NoneType. How to read the `boto3` file_obj in opencv and process further?

```
import cv2
import boto3

s3Client = boto3.client('s3')
file_path = s3Client.generate_presigned_url('get_object', Params = {'Bucket': 
'www.mybucket.com', 'Key': 'hello.txt'}, ExpiresIn = 100)
img = cv2.imread(file_path)
```

But it is reading the file as `<class 'NoneType'>`. But I need it to be read by the cv2.

Answer (score 0):

```
import urllib2

response = urllib2.urlopen(file_path)
image = response.read()
img = cv2.imread(image)
```

can you please try this